# Kivy use two files .kv

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

i'm trying to switch kv files by a function on my .py code. In my first kivy code there are few screens and in my second kivy code there is a swipebutton@carausel.Is there any way for connect the two files. I post an example: `<Screen1> id:_screen1` on another file there is: `<SwipeButton@Carousel>`. I hope someone can help me
This is the output received when I unload the first file and load the second, it doesn't break the code:
[image: output]

`
class MainApp(MDApp)
def build(self):
self.title = "Meet!"

```
    if "Colore" in impostazioni:
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = impostazioni.get("Colore")["coloresfondo"]
    else:
        print("Nulla")
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
    if "Nome" in impostazioni:
        Nome = impostazioni.get("Nome")["nome"]
        print(Nome)
    else:
        print("Non trovato")

    if "Sesso" in impostazioni:
        Sesso1 = impostazioni.get("Sesso")["sesso"]
        print(Sesso1)
    else:
        print("Non trovato")
    self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
    self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "A700"
    self.dativari = [{'id': i, 'data_index': i, 'index': 1, 'height': 48, 'text': str(calendariofile.get(str(i)))} for i in calendariofile]
    self.screen = Builder.load_file("num3.kv")
    self.root = Builder.load_file("prova.kv")
    return self.screen`
```

`#:import C kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex <SwipeButton@Carousel>: text: '' size_hint_y: None height: 48 ignore_perpendicular_swipes: True data_index: 0 min_move: 20 / self.width on__offset: app.aggiorna(root.data_index)#print(root.data_index) #app.update_index(root.data_index, self.index) canvas.before: Color: rgba: C('FFFFFF33') Rectangle: pos: self.pos size: self.size Line: rectangle: self.pos + self.size Button: text: 'delete ({}:{})'.format(root.text, root.data_index) on_press: app.elimina(root.data_index) Label: text: root.text Button: text: 'archive' on_press: app.passachat(root.data_index) RecycleView: data: app.dativari viewclass: 'SwipeButton' do_scroll_x: False scroll_timeout: 100 RecycleBoxLayout: orientation: 'vertical' size_hint_y: None height: self.minimum_height default_size_hint: 1, None`

Answer (score 1):

If the two `kv` files do not redefine the same classes, then you can just load them both.

If the two `kv` files do redefine the same classes, then you can use [Builder.unload_file()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.builder.html#kivy.lang.builder.BuilderBase.unload_file) to unload one before loading the other. Note that loading/unloading `kv` files will not affect Widgets already created, it will only affect Widgets created after the change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I tried to load both file in buil() function but when I call function to switch screen2 doesn't show anything. I tried also with unload the file and load the next file but is the same result of the first.